# dynamodb getitem android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I'm trying to make a simple adnroid app that works with dynamodb and following through this tutorial:
[Link of Tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-amazon-dynamodb-document-api-with-aws-mobile-sdk-for-android-part-1/)

I have been able to connect with the dbClient and access the table. I can successfully perform the dbTable.putItem and also other methods like dbTable.getTableDescription.

I'm having trouble understanding how to execute and dbTable.getItem method which requires a Primitive as an input. I don't quite understand how to use the Hashkey or primary key.

My table looks like this:
[Click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7ioX.jpg)
these are the hash keys
[Primary Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDP9n.jpg)

When I execute this line of code:

```
 Document doc = dbTable.getItem(new Primitive("1"));
```

where 1 is the value of the first value in the table.

I get this error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: hash key type does not match the one
>   in table defination
>           at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.document.Table.makeKey(Table.java:720)
>           at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.document.Table.getItem(Table.java:298)
>           at com.example.user.dynamodb.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:65)

Comment: Can you check what is the hashKey that you configured when you created the table in DynamoDB?

Comment: @Karthikeyan I edited the OP please see the image. Is the Primary key equal to the Hashkey? Is the image the Hashkey you mean or something else. Can I ask how to determine the hashkey?

Comment: Can you try `new Primitive(1)` where you pass in 1 without the string?

Comment: passing 1 gives the same error

Comment: DynamoDB supports two types of primary keys, a Hash Key and a Hash and Range Key.

A Hash Key consists of a single attribute that uniquely identifies an item.
A Hash and Range Key consists of two attributes that together, uniquely identify an item.

In your table, can you find what did you set as the primary key? Is just 'seq' your  hash key?

Comment: We are tracking this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/574